# Gromov-Hausdorff relative compactness without curvature restrictions

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, metric-spaces

A famous theorem of Gromov says that the set of compact Riemannian manifolds with $Ric \geq c$ and $\text{diam} \leq D$ is relatively compact in the Gromov-Hausdorff metric. Chapter 10 of the [book](http://www.math.psu.edu/petrunin/papers/alexandrov/bbi.pdf) by Burago-Burago-Ivanov lists a few other such compactness theorems, but they are all dependent on some variant of global curvature bounds.

My question is, are there examples of such compactness theorems which do not use assumptions on the curvature? In other words, is it reasonable to expect some kind of compactness theorem under uniform control of a combination of other geometric quantities like volumes of balls, curve lengths, diameter, injectivity radius etc., but not curvature?

This is mainly a reference request, I am trying to get a feel for whether there is a metamathematical principle which tells us that one cannot expect relative compactness in the Gromov-Hausdorff metric without curvature restrictions.

Comment: The proofs of at least some of these theorems always use the curvature assumptions only to obtain volume bounds of balls. You can state the theorems using the volume bounds directly.

Comment: What do you mean by "global curvature bound"? A condition such as $\mathrm{Ric}\ge c$ is typically a local condition.

Comment: My advice is to study the proofs of the theorems and try to prove this on your own.  That's better than getting the answer from someone else. This is all pretty straightforward stuff.

Comment: 7.4.15 in Burago--Burago--Ivanov answers your question.

Comment: @YCor Curvature is a local concept. By "global curvature bound", we typically mean an inequality that holds everywhere on $M$.

Comment: @SebastianGoette a local property means a local property checked at all points. See for instance https://sites.math.washington.edu/~lee/Books/Riemannian/c1.pdf. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_property